# What can i do to parse javascript classes from java?

Tags: javascript, java, parsing

I need to parse JavaScript from java.
I have already tried the NashornScriptEngine (builtin in the jdk), and RhinoScriptEngine, but they both (apparently) do not support the "class" keyword.

This is what i tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    RhinoScriptEngineFactory factory = new RhinoScriptEngineFactory();
    RhinoScriptEngine engine = (RhinoScriptEngine) factory.getScriptEngine();

    engine.eval(new FileReader("js/SomeClass.js"));
}
```

And this is the content of SomeClass.js:

```
class SomeTestClass {
}

function start() {
    print("hello")
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: identifier is a reserved word: class in eval at line number 0 at column number 6
    at org.mozilla.javascript.engine.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:124)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at com.clut.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:21)
```

So what can i do to parse javascript containing classes?
I can even use another library if its needed

Comment: You are going to have to transpile the code to ES5 if you want to use Rhino.

Comment: I am not forced to used Rhino, i can use any library

Comment: @MinusFour should i edit the question to "How to parse ES6 javascript from java?" ?

Comment: _"How to parse ES6 javascript from java?"_ - Which would make the question even more off-topic -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Do you just need to parse the code or execute it?

Comment: @Olivier i need to parse and execute it

Answer (score 0):

I found out that GraalVm has builtin javascript parsing